# NGINX setup for a React route that accepts a query parameters

Tags: reactjs, nginx, routes

I am new to ReactJs and Nginx but what I wanted to fulfil was

In my reactjs, there is a button that will redirect to an SSO url with the ssotarget as a query parameter.  The ssotarget is a react route in my routes.

```
Redirect URL:http://sso-url.com/login?ssotarget=http://my-react/my-route
```

I also have an **nginx **server serving the react js .

Once the authentication is successful, the SSO server (still in the same browser tab) will forward to the ssotarget url.

How do I code or setup that when the SSO target redirect to my website (see below), it will be catch by the react route and proceed with decoding the response?

```
http://my-react/my-route?response=somebase64string
```